# Linux@Virtualbox: Access from Host (pingable) and ability to access Internet (outside)

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu that's being installed on Virtualbox and then I'd want to access my application from host via url e.g 192.168.50.100 and I managed to achieve that via

> vmsettings -> network -> host-only

But I'm unable to access the Internet (outside e.g Google.com) from VM - I'd want to have both, is it possible?

OS Host: Windows10

OS Guest: Debian

edit:

Solution is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

- Use NAT in vbox settings
- Add Port-forwarding e.g

> HOST IP: 10.1.14.10
>
> HOST PORT: 44444
>
> GUEST IP: 10.0.2.5
>
> GUEST PORT: 80

Answer (score 0):

you could use a second network interface within you guest and set it to NAT or Bridge.
When you do so make sure you have configured the second network interface within you debian guest by editing this file: /etc/network/interfaces

[How to Setup Network Interfaces of Virtualbox Guest](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)

[How to Config /etc/network/interfaces](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration)